# The tensor product of two path algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Given two path algebras $A$ and $B$, for example, A=:   $1\to2$   B=: $1\to2\to3$, is the tensor product of A and B over a field $k$ a 
path algebra? if yes, how to represent it by a quiver? also, how to construct $(A,B)$-bimodules?

Comment: 1) Paths algebras (over non-trivial quivers) have homological dimension $1$, while the tensor product of two path algebras has homological dimension $\geq 2$, so it is not a path algebra 2) What kind of question is this? There are free bimodules and any other bimodule is a quotient of a free one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be realized as a quotient of the Cartesian product of path algebras in question. You have to mod out by some commutativity relations.

Comment: How does that work?  Specifically, which element in the tensor product would be the image of the element $(a,b)$ of the Cartesian product?  The "obvious" choice, $a\otimes b$ won't work, because addition in the Cartesian product ($(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$) doesn't match addition in the tensor product, so you won't have a homomorphism.  (Multiplication by scalars from $k$ doesn't match either unless $k$ is the two-element field.)

Comment: I think he means take the Cartesian product of the quivers and then put in commutativity relations.  For instance, if you take the quiver 1->2 and take the tensor product of this path algebra with itself you get the incidence algebra of the diamond 
  

   1
 /   \
a     b
  \ /
   0

The Hasse diagram is the quiver of this algebra, but you have the relation that the two paths to the top are the same.  

Comment: Hmm, my picture of the Hasse diagram of a diamond didn't draw well in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is

[here.](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:rALUXOAYm6wJ:daim.idi.ntnu.no/masteroppgave%3Fid%3D6346+&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShnEIQAPRW0AEL1m94jPP1ZBCFyfSzvHwPm-1XWcQZ4JJfEqJhaEYFynLCGr8jKZ8Q3-APyQVLt5TeJnjoJ4IrVBkOKknjhxJ6DgkWi7C2JXeE0BV33HC6VAQzNSifKfgK0SZj5&sig=AHIEtbSviO8hH_CCLkOUnyOTl0qfkWc8ww)

Basically you take the 1-skeleton of the products of the quivers and you say that certain paths e.g. (edge,vertex)(vertex,edge)=(vertex,edge)(edge,vertex).